# "commands out of sync; you can't run this command now" on first use of cursor

Tags: python, mysql, django, database-cursor

I am using MySQL in Django (Python).

The draft version of this code worked and was stable, but it created cursors without closing them, and I just rewrote it to manage the cursor with enter/exit. Now it is unstable.

```
class Cursor:

  def __init__ (self, db):
    self.db     = db
    self.cursor = db.DB_connection.cursor ()

  def __enter__ (self):
    return self

  def __exit__ (self, ex_type, ex_value, ex_traceback):
    if ex_value is not None:
      # log stuff
    self.cursor.close ()
    self.cursor = None

  def __del__ (self):
    if self.cursor is not None:
      # log stuff
      self.cursor.close ()

  def one (self, query, args):
    self.cursor.execute (query, args)
    return self.cursor.fetchone ()

class DB:

  def __init__ (self, my_stuff):
    self.DB_connection = connect (...)

  def get (self):
    return Cursor (self)
```

and in the application:

```
with DB_connection.get() as db:
  result = db.one ("SELECT ...", ...)
```

Sometimes this works as before, but sometimes randomly it will fail calling `db.one()`

```
_mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now
```

this exception is seen in Cursor's `__exit__`

Googling this error tells me that this means an earlier SELECT on that cursor still has un-fetched results. But this is nonsense since `with DB_connection.get() as db` creates a new cursor.

Also sometimes the process simply exists without printing any exception info. Docker log looks like this

```
www_1   | "GET /test_page HTTP/1.1" 200 16912
docker_www_1 exited with code 245
```

These crashes are non-deterministic even though the code in the view which creates the cursor is entirely deterministic.

I have added some print statements which show that there are only ever 0 or 1 cursors simultaneously in existence during the flow of the application.

In the draft version, instead of

```
with DB_connection.get() as db:
  result = db.one ("SELECT ...", ...)
```

it would have been something like

```
db = DB_connection.get()
result = db.one ("SELECT ...", ...)
```

And that was very stable, although it leaks the cursor resource. I don't think anything else significantly changed since it was stable, other than wrapping the cursor in enter/exit.

Is this the correct way to use the API?

Comment: `__exit__` is also called if there is an exception. Is it possible that in that case you don't close the connection? Currently the `# log stuff` does not really show how that is going.

Comment: It prints when the `Commands out of sync` passes through it, and not before. So this error is happening before the `with` block exits.

Comment: yes, but is there a `with` block *before*. Does the error sometimes occurs with a single `with` block, or are there multiple?

Comment: Another idea might be to close the connection already after the `one()`, so `self.cursor.execute(...); result = self.cursor.fetchone(); `self.cursor.close(); return result;`

Comment: The `with DB_connection.get() as db` is being called from a Django view handler. There is no surrounding `with` block in the application layer.

Comment: not per se a surrounding, a previous...

Comment: Within the scope of the django view handler, no other cursor is created, nor is there another `with` block. Earlier view handler invocations in the same process will have created and closed other cursors. The thing is, the *first* operation on the new cursor causes `Commands out of sync`!

Comment: Cursors are just a Python class, MySQL doesn't know or care which cursor you use, or whether it's a new cursor.  The MySQL protocol handles state at the connection level. If any of your views left unfetched results on the db connection, then that would cause this error. It doesn't matter that you call it from another view or another cursor.