# How should mysql.connector be shared correctly with threads in Django applications?

Tags: python, mysql, django, multithreading

This concerns a potential solution to [my earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77487774/commands-out-of-sync-you-cant-run-this-command-now-on-first-use-of-cursor) in which I was getting `commands out of sync; you can't run this command now` after wrapping mysql cursors in `__enter__` and `__exit__`.

I have read elsewhere that Django does not spawn new threads to handle multiple requests, but rather multiple Django processes would normally be spawned in order to achieve parallelism. Despite this advice, I began printing `Thread.ident` and `Thread.native_id` and noticed that they were changing.

Based on this, I speculatively wrote something like:

```
def db_connect ():

  t = threading.current_thread()

  if not hasattr (t, 'db_connection'):
    print (f"New MyDBConnectionClass for {t.ident}~{t.native_id}")
    t.db_connection = MyDBConnectionClass ()

  return t.db_connection.get_cursor () # This object has a __exit__ which closes the cursor
```

along with

```
class MyDBConnectionClass ():

  def __del__(self):
    t = threading.current_thread()
    print (f"MyDBConnectionClass deleted for {t.ident}~{t.native_id}")
```

the view handlers' usage of the cursors is unchanged:

```
with db_connect() as db:
  results = db.all (query, args)
```

So far this seems to have fixed the `commands out of sync` error (and the exit code 245 crash mentioned in the original question).

`MyDBConnectionClass.__delete__` is not being called, but various instances are created for a few different `ident` values.

My current hypothesis is that there is some sort of thread pool going on, and my application was crashing unpredictably because *sometimes* (often) a view would be handled in the thread which created the initial connection, but sometimes not. This experiment seems to show that giving each thread a distinct connection works, which makes sense, but I am unsatisfied because:

- the Thread objects are apparently not being deleted (or else something else is preventing `MyDBConnection.__del__` from being called)
- this doesn't agree with the documentation and examples I have read elsewhere
- it's messy, and Django has a fairly clean design as far as I have seen -- I think I must be missing something

So, what is the correct way to handle mysql connection and cursor objects so that I can do

```
with my_connection_wrapper.get_cursor() as my_cursor_wrapper:
  my_cursor_wrapper.foo ()
```

freely in Django views without leaking resources and without causing thread affinity instability issues (assuming that really is the problem)?

Answer (score 1):

You can't share db connections between threads, unless you use some mutex or something to synchronize the threads. I.e. while one thread is using the db connection, other threads must wait. This kind of spoils the benefits of running parallel threads.

The common alternative is for each thread to open its own db connection, so they each can have their own state on their respective db connections.

The MySQL Connector/Python offers connection pooling for this purpose. Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-connection-pooling.html

The idea is that the app has a fixed pool of db connections, and each thread may request to "borrow" a connection from that pool. The thread does its queries, and then as promptly as possible, uses `close()` to release the connection back to the pool for another thread to use.

Comment: How would I ensure that the thread pool is big enough?

Comment: Connection pool, not thread pool. How many threads does each process of your Python app run concurrently?

Comment: I have no idea. I'm just discovering that apparently it's a thing.

Comment: Well, start small. I'd try 5. As you may notice as you read the manual page I linked to, if your code requests a db connection from the pool and there aren't any available, the `connect()` function throws a `PoolError`, so you should check for that in your code, and retry if necessary.

Comment: The other strategy is that you must write your code to be "courteous" about the connections. I mean, don't request a connection if you don't need it, and once your code does its SQL work, close the connection as promptly as possible. Think of it like borrowing a book from the library. :-) If your code uses db connections briefly in this way, a small pool can serve a larger number of threads easily.